# ThreadPool Exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I need to use 60 threads in one time(parallelly) and for it I use ThreadPool. I have exception here:

```
temp = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < temp; j++) {
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object notUsed) {
      RequestToRajons(rajs_ip[j].ToString(),rajs_name[j].ToString(), sql_str, base_str, saveFileDialog1,j); 
   });
}
```

It's gives me exception that `j=1`(array out of range). But I have a contidion! 
If I use a breakpoint with step, I haven't got an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the classic for/capture issue, because you are "capturing" `j`, and there **is only one `j`**. All your threads are processing using the same `j` variable; the *value* they see is indeterminate, but the last several threads will most likely see the **exit** value of the loop, i.e. one too many.

Instead:

```
for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < temp; loopIndex++)
{
    int j = loopIndex;
    // the following line has not changed at all
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object notUsed) { RequestToRajons(rajs_ip[j].ToString(),rajs_name[j].ToString(), sql_str, base_str, saveFileDialog1,j); });
}
```

it sounds silly, but you now have a `j` per loop iteration, because the scope of the *capture* depends on the *declaration scope* of the variable. Here, `j` is defined **inside** the loop. In the `for` loop, the variable is *technically* defined **outside** the loop.

---

Another way to do this is to use the parameter to the thread-pool:

```
for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < temp; loopIndex++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object ctx) {
        int j = (int) ctx;
        // stuff involving j
    }, loopIndex); // <=== see we're passing it in, rather than capturing
}
```

---

Here's an expanded version of how "captured variables" and anonymous methods work, the over-simplified version; firstly, the compiler does this for you:

```
class CaptureContext { // <== the real name is gibberish
    public int j; // yes it is a field; has to be, so `ref` and `struct` etc work
    public void SomeMethod(object notUsed) {
        RequestToRajons(rajs_ip[j].ToString(),rajs_name[j].ToString(), sql_str, base_str, saveFileDialog1,j); 
    }
    // it might also be capturing "this"; I can't tell from your example
}
```

and your method becomes (because `j` is *technically* defined outside the loop):

```
var ctx = new CaptureContext();
for (ctx.j = 0; ctx.j < temp; ctx.j++) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ctx.SomeMethod);
}
```

now; can you see that there is only one "capture" object, and that we're using it at random points in times where `ctx.j` is not necessarily what we thought it was? The fix rewrites that as:

```
for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < temp; loopIndex++) {
    var ctx = new CaptureContext();
    ctx.j = loopIndex;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ctx.SomeMethod);
}
```

here, can you see there is a "capture" object **per iteration**, which is because the `j` is declared **inside** the loop? The "what is a new capture context" depends on the **scope** of the variables that are captured.

Comment: At first look the same thing that I wrote. But it work - thanks. Could you explain me more details please.

Comment: @Oleg I already added a few lines trying to explain that - is it still unclear?

Comment: @Oleg expanded with a lot more detail